# $.each() to dsiplay list

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to find out how i can get my list of arrays to display.
I'm currently using a `.each` function to get the list from the array but when i use .text to populate the `span` tag with classes it only displays that last items

Here's my jquery code

```
$.each (json.consultants, function(i) {  
   console.log(json.consultants[i].firstname) 
     $('.consultantsfirstname').text(json.consultants[i].firstname)
     $('.consultantslastname').text(json.consultants[i].lastname)

 })
```

I would like to find away to display the list of all that shows up in the array
not just the last one.

Comment: this is not going to work since you're overwriting the text everytime. you need to append it to a string or you can create an ordered list and then append it to your `span`.

Comment: could you elaborate? I'm familiary with .appendTto() but not quite familiary with where i would place it. if that makes sense @Sushil

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to use $('.consultantsfirstname')? That has the potential to not be unique, and is also why it's overwriting everytime.

Comment: There's no commitment on the class name, if Id will help separate and identify them then that works as well

Comment: Class name will work as long as it is unique for each span you want to make. $('.consultantsfirstname') will return the same span every time, for every consultant. If you did $('.' + json.consultants[i].firstname + json.consultants[i].lastname) you could use class names fine, and it would be unique for every consultant, but you need to make sure that those spans exist in your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your text every time.

Try:

```
$.each (json.consultants, function(i) {  
 console.log(json.consultants[i].firstname) 
 $('.consultantsfirstname').text($('.consultantsfirstname').text() + json.consultants[i].firstname)
 $('.consultantslastname').text($('.consultantsfirstname').text() + json.consultants[i].lastname)

})
```

IF you only want to display the data anyway you could do:

```
$.each (json.consultants, function(i) {  
 console.log(json.consultants[i].firstname) 
 $('#list').html($('#list').html() + json.consultants[i].firstname);
 $('#list').html($('#list').html() + ' ');
 $('#list').html($('#list').html() + json.consultants[i].lastname);
 $('#list').html($('#list').html() + '<br />');
});
```

With HTML

```
<div id="list" />
```

Comment: This works however it groups them into the same span, into one

Comment: Right, $('.consultantsfirstname') is not unique. It will return the same span everytime. I think you means $('.' + json.consultants[i].firstname)

Comment: In the second .text or first.text?

Comment: Also if there's a more effective method of displaying the list by all means chime in.. .thanks for all the help

Comment: I edited the post above with a simpler way of doing it. It's harder to put code in comments than posts :/